# Material Design Mat-footer-row gives Cannot read property 'template' of undefined

Tags: angular, material-design

When ever I add the the following:

I get the following message: Cannot read property 'template' of undefined

```
.....
<ng-container matColumnDef="Price">         
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Price</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let prod">{{prod.Price}}</mat-cell>
    <mat-footer-cell></mat-footer-cell>
</ng-container> 
<ng-container matColumnDef="LineTotal">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Total</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let prod"> {{prod.LineTotal}} </mat-cell>
    <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef="let prod">{{prod.LineTotal}}
    </mat-footer-cell>
 </ng-container>

 <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
 <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
 <**mat-footer-row** *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-footer-row>
```

If I remove mat-footer-row the table is rendered properly.
     displayedColumns: string[] = [];
     ...
     vm.displayedColumns.push('Price');

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

instead of:

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```